# Syntax error While declaring public method in Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, class

I wrote one class in javascript. when i try to declare method as a public method it is giving me syntax error. I am providing two cases there is only difference is enter.

1st Case showing syntax error :

```
var myclass=(function(){ 

function takeResponse(){.....}
.
.
.
function takeResponse(){.....}
      return  
      {
            takeResponse: takeResponse, 
            takeResponse_1: takeResponse_1, 
            takeResponse_2: takeResponse_2,
            takeResponse_3: takeResponse_3
      };
})();
```

2nd Case does not have syntax error :

```
var TestUtils=(function(){

function takeResponse(URL)
{
    var Response=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result){
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
    return Response;
}

function takeResponse_1(URL,Data)
{
    var Response=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        $.ajax({
            url:URL,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(Data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function(result){          
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
    return Response;
}

function takeResponse_2(URL,Data)
{
    var Response=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var res = $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(Data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        console.log("======"+res);
        resolve(res);
    });
    return Response;
}

function takeResponse_3(URL)
{
    var Response=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var res = $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            type: "DELETE",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        console.log("======"+res);
        resolve(res);
    });
    return Response;
}
return  {
    takeResponse: takeResponse, 
    takeResponse_1: takeResponse_1, 
    takeResponse_2: takeResponse_2,
    takeResponse_3: takeResponse_3
};
})();
```

I am not getting why it is showing error in 1st Case.
can anyone tell me the difference between this two code ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you put in an actual code that we can run and see the error? Now you have multiple declarations for takeResponse-function and no declaration for takeResponse_x so we don't really see what is it you are trying to do.

Comment: ok. I will post.

Comment: Issue is with the return statement in first code (in which { is starting in new line) so javascript will insert a semicolon after return and treat { as new line

try placing return and { in same lines in first code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because javascript is assuming that the return is done in one line and attaches a `;` after it like

```
 return ; 
      {
            takeResponse: takeResponse, 
            takeResponse_1: takeResponse_1, 
            takeResponse_2: takeResponse_2,
            takeResponse_3: takeResponse_3
      };
```

This behavior is called Automatic semicolon insertion, 
read about it [here](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/)